# Check customer login in external script

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, login

There are many snippets available to get customer login status in a script. I'm using this:

[root]/tools/testlogin.php

```
require_once ('../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
if ($session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'))) {
    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo 'logged in';
    } else {
        echo 'not logged in!';
    }
} else {
    // not even a session.
    echo 'not logged in';
}
```

It worked a couple of times earlier, but no matter what I do, I don't get the 'logged in' message anymore. I've logged out & back in at the shop. After logout from the shop, I also noticed the 'not logged in' message appear.

I've tried clearing browser sessions, Magento cache etc. Didn't work. 
I've tried calling `Mage::app('default');`. No luck.

The only way I can make it work, 100% of the time, is by using Opera browser and putting the script not in /tools/ but in the root of the shop. For an isolated test, this is OK, but not for a complete application I'm building.

My cookie settings in Magento backoffice: (all default)
Cookie path: < empty >
Cookie domain: < empty >

If I specify a Cookie path: / 
The testlogin script doesn't even work in the root anymore.

I've also set cache headers in my script:

  `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
  header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past`

I'm afraid I've run out of options. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to make it work.

Step 1: Configure in the Magento Config the `Cookie Path` to be `/` via: *System > Configuration > GENERAL > Web > Session Cookie Management*

Step 2: Clear all your cookies of the domain or use an 'Incognito' window.
Your previous try was setting extra cookies on the subdir. This made it a mess.

Step 3: Then you can use this script in a subdir:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once ('../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

if ( Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
    echo 'logged in';
} else {
    echo 'not logged in!';
}
```

You can check your browser cookies. If you have multiple cookies with the same name: this means trouble. Because some cookies are only valid on subdirs, strange things will happen.

Comment: That worked! I guess I had conflicting cookies when I tried the cookie-path "/" earlier. Thanks!